# vuetify v-alert error on edge and firefox

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My vuetify application works fine in chrome, but is just a blank screen in Edge and firefox.

Here is what i have from the devtools and it looks like vAlerts may be the issue.

I have removed every v-alert just to be sure, but the error still occurs in Edge and Firefox.

[image]

SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add this in vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify']
}
```